# How to derive moment of inertia for a thin disc?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

[Wikipedia's article on moment of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia) provides examples of how to derive the moments of inertia for different bodies:

$$I_P=\iiint_Q p(x,y,z)||\mathbf{r}||^2 dV$$

It gives an example of how to derive the moment of inertia for a thin rod:

$$I_{C,rod}=\iiint_Q p(x,y,z)||\mathbf{r}||^2dV=\int_{-\frac{l}{2}}^{\frac{l}{2}} px^2s dx=\left.px\frac{x^3}{3}\right\rvert_{-\frac{l}{2}}^\frac{l}{2}=\frac{ps}{3}\left(\frac{l^3}{8}+\frac{l^3}{8}\right)=\frac{ml^2}{12}$$

That was pretty straightfoward, but I don't understand why you need a double integral for the example that follows, the derivation for a thin disk:

$$I_{C,disk}=\iiint_Q p(x,y,z)||\mathbf{r}||^2dV=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^Rpr^2sr\, dr\, d\theta=2{\pi}ps\frac{R^4}{4}=\frac{1}{2}mR^2$$

I know it is because $V({r,\theta})$ is a function of two variables, but I still don't understand where those limits come from. Could someone please explain?

Comment: Do you understand [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system)?

Comment: @Ghoster Yes, I do

Comment: What range of polar coordinates describes a thin disk of radius $R$, when the origin is at the center?

Comment: @Ghoster Would it be 0 to $2\pi$?

Comment: There are *two* polar coordinates. That’s the range for $\theta$. It’s not the range for $r$.

Comment: @Ghoster Oh right. I kind of get it now. Thanks

Comment: If you’ve never done a 2D integral in polar coordinates, try calculating the area of a circle, by integration, using polar coordinates.

Comment: @Ghoster I should try that

Comment: @Ghoster Would the integral setup look like $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^r dr d\theta$?

Comment: No. That integral would give $2\pi r$, which is not the area of a circle. The [infinitesimal element of area](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2126182/infinitesimal-area-in-polar-coordinates) in polar coordinates is $dA=(dr)(r\,d\theta)=r\,dr\,d\theta$. Notice how it has the proper dimensions to be an area, while your $dr\,d\theta$ does not.

Comment: @Ghoster Ok yeah thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you calculate the moment of inertia for a thin rod, you reduce the problem to one dimension because you're only considering it's length.

A disk is a 2D object, hence you need those two spatial coordinates to characterize it, the radial and angular components. Their origin becomes straighforward once you learn about the "polar coordinate system", which I encourage you to investigate. As for the limits of integration, think of a straight line of length R with an edge at the origin. Then rotate that line 2π radians around the origin, a full 360° turn that is. This will draw the disk/circle you are trying to parameterize.